# Pull-To-Refresh: ListView breaks while animating

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

**I am using this PullToRefresh Code:**

**https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView**

**XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_listview_grey" >

    <eu.erikw.PullToRefreshListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:divider="@color/bg_listview_grey"
        android:dividerHeight="6dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity Code related to the ListView:**

```
listView = (PullToRefreshListView) view
        .findViewById(R.id.feedListView);
footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, listView, false);
feedListView.addFooterView(footerView);
listAdapter = new DefaultFeedAdapter((Activity) getSherlockActivity(),
        list_items, listView);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

feedListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        // what is the bottom item that is visible
        int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
        // is the bottom item visible & not loading more already ? Load
        // more !
        if ((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && totalItemCount >= 3
                && !LoadingNextData && !noMoreItems) {
            lastId = listAdapter.values.get(totalItemCount - 3).id;
            LoadingNextData = true;
            new GetNewItems().execute("" + lastId);
        }
    }
});

listView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        new RefreshList().execute("");
    }
});

private class RefreshFeed extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    //adds items at the top of the list if there are any.
    //But even without any new items ie.. without touching
    //the listView, it breaks.
}
```

**The problem is:**

[image]

> While loading, it breaks 40% of the bottom listView and when it gets
> loaded it breaks some 20% of the listViewand finally shows the whole
> listView.

Am I missing something? Please help.

Thank You.

Comment: ListView height is your problem?

Comment: I have also noticed this bug before. That aside, after thorough attempts with other libraries, this one is still the best *Pull-To-Refresh ListView* available.

Comment: @Phil Its not the best, its just simple and specific to ListViews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a solution to your problem but use this:

**https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh**

Though it says

> PLEASE NOTE, THIS PROJECT IS NO LONGER BEING MAINTAINED

It works flawlessly with smooth interface.

Like @Udi Oshi suggested you can also go with a Gmail Like pull to refresh:

**https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh**

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a known issue of this library as it still happens even after they closed this issue in their [Issues on git](https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView/issues/3)

I would suggest you to use the new [Pull to refresh - Gmail like](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh). works like a charm. have fun